# How to equialy divide integer by 5

Tags: php

This is for an incremental webgame:
How can I split an integer in pieces of 5 and also keep the remaining value?
So lets say I got an integer who's value is 12, I want to substract 2x5 and the remaining would be 2.
basically to store my workers in houses, every house stores 5 workers so the first 2 houses would be 5/5 and the third 2/5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `%` which will give you the remaining
example:

```
$workers = 12;
$houseStorage = 5;
$fullHouses = (int) ($workers / $houseStorage);
$remainingWorkers = $workers % $houseStorage;
```

The `$fullHouses` will be 2 and the `$remainingWorkers` will be also 2

You can play with this example at https://3v4l.org/fi4d3

**Edit**

`$fullHouses = (int) ($workers / $houseStorage);`

Here I'm casting to `(int)` so that no float is given.